# How to set PHP Selenium path like "Require_Once" and "use Directory" in Windows

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to set below code path in PHP selenium webdriver. I have added the path but is it correct or Wrong. Pls let me know Thanks.

```
namespace Facebook\WebDriver;
use C:\xampp\htdocs\WebdriverFacebook\lib\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use C:\xampp\htdocs\WebdriverFacebook\lib\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\newapp\vendor\autoload.php');
```

Comment: namespace and use: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

require: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php (require_once is identical to require)

Comment: Not fixed, I have issue regarding giving path, your provided link is used for PHP, not for Selenium Webdriver, Thaks for your response

Comment: @AazadRkhan You do know, that the code snipped you posted is in fact PHP code and the links Stefano provided are links to the PHP doc describing how to use the `use`, `namespace` and `require` keywords correctly. Your question is too broad to be answered, please specify which part is troublesome for you.